# Disable Aptana Red/Yellow Squiggly Lines

Tags: aptana

Ten minutes of Googling keeps returning the same answer that is not valid in my case.  I want to disable whatever is Aptana is doing to make these squiggly lines.
[image]

I found several references directing to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling.  Unfortunately, that is disabled:
[image]

Is there a fast way to disable those squiggly underlines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turned off the yellow squiggly lines at

Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Warnings

Then uncheck the "Text as" option.